# Call a class (component) method from another class (component)

Tags: reactjs

I have List component and Create component.
Each component has own "handleSubmit" aync method to list all items from DynamoDB and create new item into DynamoDB. Each feature is working well.

The one I want to update is that when "handleSubmit" button clicked in Create component, I want to call LIST component's "handleSubmit" method so that I can get the updated list instead of I click the "List" button again to get the updated list.

Below is the source codes I'm using. Any idea?

```js
// LIST.js

export default class List extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      totalCount: '',
      totalItems: '',
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    await axios.get(
      'https://*****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/apiCall***',
    ).then((response)=>{
      this.setState({
        totalCount: "Total Item: " + response.data.Count,
        totalItems: JSON.stringify(response.data.Items, null, 2)
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <div className="col col-lg-2">
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-secondary">List</button>
          </div>
        </form>
        <br /><br /><div className=""><b>{this.state.totalCount}</b></div>
        <div className=""><b><pre>{this.state.totalItems}</pre></b></div>
        </>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
// CREATE.js

export default class Create extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: ''
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const inputValue = event.target.value;
    const stateField = event.target.name;
    this.setState({
      [stateField]: inputValue,
    });
    console.log(this.state.message);
  }
  async handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { message } = this.state;
    await axios.post(
      'https://*****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/apiCall***',
      { create: `${message}` },
    ).then((response)=>{
      this.setState({
        message: ""
      })

      // HERE!! I want to call LIST's "handlerSubmit" button

    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className="col col-lg-10">
            <input
                type="text"
                name="message"
                className="form-control"
                placeholder="Type your message"
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                value={this.state.message}
            />
        </div>
        <div className="col col-lg-2">
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-outline-secondary">Create</button>
        </div>
        </form>
        </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parent component that renders both `List` and `Create`, pass a callback to `Create`, which will trigger the `List` component's `handleSubmit` method.

It can be like this:

1. **Parent Component**:

```
class ParentComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.listRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* Pass the ref to the List component */}
        <List ref={this.listRef} />
        
        {/* Pass the function to the Create component */}
        <Create callListUpdate={() => this.listRef.current.handleSubmit(new Event('click'))} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

2. **Create Component**:

```
async handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const { message } = this.state;
  await axios.post(
    'https://*****.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/default/apiCall***',
    { create: `${message}` },
  ).then((response)=>{
    this.setState({
      message: ""
    });
    
    this.props.callListUpdate();
  });
}
```

With this approach, when the form in `Create` component is submitted after the axios post request, the `List` component's `handleSubmit` method is triggered, thus updating the list.